# Someone deleted the accepted answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer, link-only-answers

I was asking a question and got a clear answer which solved my problem. I accepted this answer.
A bit later someone added another answer which was not helpful at all. The accepted answer has been deleted afterwards.

Can we see who deleted it? Is this really the way to go to get more reputation?
Here the link to my question: [org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient is deprecated in selenium 3.14.0 - What should be used instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908461/org-openqa-selenium-remote-internal-apachehttpclient-is-deprecated-in-selenium-3?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

@CoreyGoldberg gave the accepted answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Looks like it was deleted after being flagged as a link-only answer. The answer read, in its entirety:

> The http client was switched to okhttp: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

I can't see how that falls under link-only. The URL itself is descriptive; and even absent the link, OkHttp is explicitly named in the text. Probably another case of "it looks short and a significant portion of it is clickable so it must be link-only". Ugh.

Two moderators appear to have handled the flag independently. One declined the flag. The other deleted the answer anyway. Since I'm clearly siding with the one who declined the flag I undeleted the answer.

Comment: Names hidden to protect the guilty? Yeah, I wouldn’t want to be caught agreeing with me, either. :-)